# run cygwin command through batch file

Tags: batch-file, ssh, cygwin, rsync

I am running a rsync ssh command in cygwin in windows. Upon this, password is asked and if given, it does the intended task. Now I want to put these all tasks in one batch file, which can be run on one click.

Thanks

Comment: And what problem are you having?  Is there one?  What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Set up an `authorized_keys` file on the server so that you can ssh in from your local machine without using a password (check the security implications of this carefully). You can find instructions for this in many places, including the official documentation.

Step 2: Add Cygwin's `bin` directory to your Windows `PATH` environment variable. If you don't want to do it permanently, you could write that into your batch file.

Step 3: Write your one-line batch file using the exact same rsync command line you used in Cygwin. Pathnames should not need translating unless you expect the shell to expand a wild card. If you use any sort of quoting then that might need adjusting.

Step 4: Configure Windows to run programs with one click, instead of double click. Not sure how you do that; I don't use Windows much.